# My website gives blank page - PHP FPM Error

Tags: php, nginx, centos

I'm trying to install pterodactyl server management panel on my CentOS 7 server.. I did chown and chmod stuff like docs told me so. But when i try to open the website i see a blank page (phpinfo.php file works like it should work)

output of www-error.log

```
[22-Nov-2017 16:49:58 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/var/www/html/pterodactyl/storage/logs/laravel-2017-11-22.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/pterodactyl/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:107
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/pterodactyl/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/RotatingFileHandler.php(107): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/pterodactyl/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler->write(Array)
#2 /var/www/html/pterodactyl/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(337): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/pterodactyl/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(616): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException), Array)
#4 /var/www/html/pterodactyl/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/Writer.php(203): Monolog\Logger->error(Ob in /var/www/html/pterodactyl/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 107
```

Comment: What isn't clear about that error message?

Answer (score 0):

You should create the following folder `/var/www/html/pterodactyl/storage/logs/` then change the permission so Apache or Nginx can write to that folder.